# Connecting AKS and Web App with VNet integration

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-appservice, vnet

I'm trying to connect my Web App to the AKS LoadBalancer through the VNet integration instead of a public load balancer.

The problem here is to integrate VNet into the web app, the VNet needs to have a subnet delegated to Microsoft.Web/serverFarms. On the other hand, AKS cannot be assigned with a subnet that has a delegation.
I have found [this](https://blog.novanet.no/appservices-k8s-vnet-integration/) that seemingly has done the exact same thing but it seems to be old as I cannot reproduce the same result. Either I get
 `VNET aks-subnet is missing a delegation to Microsoft.Web/serverFarms. Please add the delegation and try again.` or `aks-subnet cannot be used as it's a delegated subnet`

I have tried to add two subnets one with delegation to managedClusters and use that for my AKS but the same `... cannot be used as it's a delegated subnet` happens.

sidenote: I'm using the bicep script to deploy.

Comment: Hi kasravi. You need to create a dedicated subnet for the VNET integration. The subnet must not be used by another service. If you have IP address space left in your VNET you can just create a new subnet with /27 as a minimum (in prod use /26) and delegate it to `Microsoft.Web/serverFarms`.

Comment: so I need to have two subnets, /16 without delegation and /27 with?

Comment: If the /16 is for your AKS and /27 for your App Service VNET integration, then yes, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

VNET Integration requires a dedicated subnet for the App Service that is going to be integrated. This means the subnet cannot be used for any other purpose, i.E. hosting AKS or VMs.

[image: VNET Integration]

The App Service can then reach services in other subnets on the same VNET or in peered VNETs.

[Subnet Size Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#subnet-requirements) are a minimum of /27 and Microsoft recommends /26 for production grade environments.

It is sometimes a little tricky to troubleshoot issues with VNET integration, some good hints are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#troubleshooting).